# MVVM executes all codes at once in Execute Command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, progress-bar

I am using MVVM solution provided in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572103/change-foreground-of-textblock-if-method-throw-an-exception)

**XAML**

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="StatusProgressBar" IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsIndeterminate, Mode=OneWay}" Height="18" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FF05438D" />
```

**ViewModel**

Notice here in DoExecuteGetIpCommand() method if i do same thing in code behind on content rendered event works correctly but in mvvm all codes fires at same time so progress bar update after all time consuming process.

So i want to set ProgressBar IsIndeterminate Property true while time consuming method is working after done finally set IsIndeterminate to false. any idea to this and why it is happening but working fine in code behind Content rendered event.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool _isIndeterminate;
    private string _ipAdrress;
    private bool _errorOccured;        
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    GetPublicIP getPublicIP = new GetPublicIP();


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

   /*
    public bool IpIndeterminate
    {
        get { return _isIndeterminate; } 
        set
        {
            _isIndeterminate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IpIndeterminate));
        }
    }
    */

     //OR

    //IsIndeterminate here is problem
    public bool IsIndeterminate => _isIndeterminate;

    public string IpAddress => _ipAdrress;
    public Brush IpForeground => _errorOccured ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.IndianRed) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    public FontWeight IpFontWeight => _errorOccured ? FontWeights.SemiBold : FontWeights.Normal;


    public ICommand GetIpCommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(param => DoExecuteGetIpCommand()); }
    }        

    private async void DoExecuteGetIpCommand()
    {
        _isIndeterminate = true;
        try
        {                
            _errorOccured = false;
            //_ipAdrress = await MyService.GetIpAddress();
            _ipAdrress = await getPublicIP.GetIPAddressAsync();//time consuming method.
        }
        finally
        {
             //Commented this because progress bar immediately Is indeterminate go false.
            //_isIndeterminate = false;
        }

        if (await getPublicIP.ExceptionOccursAsync() == true)
        {
            _errorOccured = true;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsIndeterminate));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IpAddress));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IpForeground));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IpFontWeight));            
    }
}    

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute"); //NOTTOTRANS

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members


    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

Comment: That's because you notify about the property changes only at the end of the method. Isn't it obvious?

Comment: @dymanoid I also used 2nd method which is commented code as OR part does same thing even if on property changed is not in method

Comment: If the only difference is the commented code, then even in this case you only notify about property changes at the end of the method. Please read carefully about properties, fields, and `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

Comment: @dymanoid Okay i got it so i need to execute/repeat OnNotifyPropertyChange(nameof(xyz)); each time ? e.g on after setting IsIndeterminate = true; and another after false ?? is it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your code like this: (as dymanoid said)

```
private async void DoExecuteGetIpCommand()
{
    _isIndeterminate = true;

    //Tell the UI that something changed...
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsIndeterminate));

    try
    {                
        _errorOccured = false;
        _ipAdrress = await getPublicIP.GetIPAddressAsync();//time consuming method.
    }
    finally
    {
        _isIndeterminate = false;
    }

    if (await getPublicIP.ExceptionOccursAsync() == true)
    {
        _errorOccured = true;
    }
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsIndeterminate));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IpAddress));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IpForeground));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IpFontWeight));            
}
```